# Yii 2 - how to pass a variable to main view file to the renderer?

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I basically tried nothing since I haven't found anything in the docs I checked.

I basically want to pass a variable ie. `$balance` so it would be available in the scope of `layouts/main.php` file:

Where can I say something like:

```
$balance = MyClass::myMethod();

return $this->render('main', [
    'balance' => $balance,
]);
```

Thank you. Hope anyone understands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// layouts/main.php
var_dump($this->params);

// action method
$this->view->params['balance'] = $balance;
```

Also take a look http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-views.html#using-blocks

Answer (score 2):

Assumption: you are using the advanced template and have a directory structure similar to [image].

The process starts around \yii\base\View->beginContent(), it returns the following: [image].

By defaults ./frontend/views/layouts/base.php is called as the 'viewFile'; which in turns loads _clear which in turn loads main, which finally displays the contents of $content.

In order to override the default value of $content, overriding the default behavior of *View->beginContent() is necessary.

Try creating a method defined as ./frontend/controllers/*Controller->beginContent($viewFile, $params = []) {/*...*/} and see if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can send that variable to view file first like,

```
$balance = MyClass::myMethod();

return $this->render('myview', [
'balance' => $balance,
]);
```

So you can create a file myview.php in `views/controller_name/myview.php`

There you can access the variable directly `$balance`. Now you can pass this variable to main.php(if it is your layout file) using `params` in `myview.php`.

```
$this->params['balance']  = $balance;
```

and access the variable in `main.php` by `$this->params['balance']`.